# Two variables in one shared memory

Tags: c, block, shared-memory, var

Is there a way to use one shared memory,

```
shmid = shmget (shmkey, 2*sizeof(int), 0644 | IPC_CREAT);
```

For two variables with different values?

```
int *a, *b;
a = (int *) shmat (shmid, NULL, 0);
b = (int *) shmat (shmid, NULL, 0); // use the same block of shared memory ??
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently (reading the manual) `shmat` gets you here a single block of memory, of size `2*sizeof(int)`.

If so, then you can just adjust the pointer:

```
int *a, *b;
a = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);
b = a+1;
```

Also, casting here is wrong, [for reasons listed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/1012936) (while the question is about `malloc`, the same arguments apply)

Comment: Oh.. Someone in school was teaching us to use casting with malloc.. Can't remember why.. :D Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the `shmget` and similar, but I imagine if the memory is contiguous just increment the pointer.

```
int *a, *b;
i = (int *) shmat (shmid, NULL, 0);
a = ((int *) shmat (shmid, NULL, 0)) + 1;
```

Better still, just write:

```
int *myMemory = shmat (shmid, NULL, 0);

myMemory[0] = 5;
myMemory[1] = 10;
```